# Android Downloading website HTML content

Tags: android, html, logging, download, inputstream

Hello I'm attempting to download a websites HTML content within my Logcat so that in the future I can pick out specific information in the future. But before I can do that I want to test if I can contact the website first. Currently I'm not getting an error but I'm not getting the context either.

//The public class I created

```
public class DownloadTsk extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{


    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

        String result = "";
        URL url;
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;

        try {
            url = new URL(urls[0]);

            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();

            InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(in);

            int data = reader.read();

            while (data != -1) {


                char current = (char) data;

                result += current;

                data = reader.read();



            }

            return result;


        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {


            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        return null;
    }
}
```

// Oncreate method

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    DownloadTsk task = new DownloadTsk();
    String result = null;

    try {
        result = task.execute("http://www.posh24.com/celebrities").get();

        Log.i("Content", result);


    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

//Current outcome

```
 Content: <!DOCTYPE html>
          <html>
          <head>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know if you connected successfully then you should use

```
int responseCode = urlConnection.getResponseCode();
```

And actually this is how I am getting the result from the HTTP request:

```
int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();

        if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) { //success
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            con.getInputStream()));
            String inputLine;
            StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();

            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                response.append(inputLine);
            }
            in.close();

            return response.toString();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code works and reads the page into the string.

I would use a buffer instead of reading it one character at a time
but that is a matter for another day.

I suspect you need to escape the html before writing it to the log.